# How to clear the output window in Visual Studio 2022 before each run automatically

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I have a simple .NET Core 6 application, developed via Visual Studio Community 2022.

When I press the start button in the standard toolbar, it appends the logs in the output window.

If I want to distinguish the start point of the recent run in the log's lines, I must search in the console.

There is a button in the top corner of the output window for clearing the console before the next run.

My question is, is there any setting in Visual Studio that I can set, to clear this output window automatically in each run before starting logging?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my cheat-to-win workaround. It's not exactly the same as clearing the output window but it sure gets rid of the noise.

```
Debug.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, Enumerable.Repeat(string.Empty, 100)));
```

In the past I would use the technique shown here [EnvDTE80.DTE2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2391510/5438626) to do a legitimate Clear but apparently there's no support for `System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject` in net core as mentioned here [.Net Framework but not for .Net Core](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58010881/5438626)

Comment: Debug.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, Enumerable.Range(0, 100).Select(x => x % 2 == 0 ? "." : string.Empty))); _For environments like Xamarin that suppress "identical lines"._

Comment: It's 2022 and still no setting to tick this option?? :-D